# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_15: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, lstm, text-classification, conv-neural-network

I want to feed the output of the CNN layer into LSTM layer but got an error `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_15: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2` with following code:

```
inp = Input(shape = (max_length,))
xe = Embedding(vocabulary_size, 300, weights = [embedding_matrix], trainable = False)(inp)
x = Conv1D(512,kernel_size = 2, activation='relu',kernel_initializer = "he_uniform")(xe)
x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = LSTM(128)(x)
x = Dense(11, activation = "sigmoid")(x)
```

inputs shapes:

```
embedding_matrix: (26441, 300)
inp : TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(3146)])
X_train :(1432, 3146)
Y_train: (1432, 11)
vocabulary_size: 26441
max_length: 3146
```

Someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you apply `GlobalMaxPooling1D`, it returns the tensor with shape `(batch_size, 512)`. As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalMaxPool1D), this layer **downsamples the input representation by taking the maximum value over the time dimension**. You have two options either not to use `GlobalMaxPool1D` (you can instead use local pooling layers such as `MaxPool1D`) or you can use [`RepeatVector`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RepeatVector) to change the shape of output of `GlobalMaxPool1D` from `(batch_size, 512)` to `(batch_size, n, 512)` where `n` is the parameter to `RepeatVector` defining, how many times you want the sequence to be repeated.